# how to persist current date selected while though other date is selected in dojo

Tags: dojo

I am trying to have a dojo dijit calendar which should show Today's date selected default all the time.

Even when the user selects another date, Today's date should always be selected.

I tried searching in many places, but could not find the answer.

Is the a dojo limitation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dojo already provides a different classname for the current day, called `.dijitCalendarCurrentDate`. So you can style that the way you want. The moment you select the current day, the class is removed, so you won't see it anymore then.

An example:

```css
.claro .dijitCalendarCurrentDate {
    background-color: #cfe5fa;
    border: solid 1px #b5bcc7;
}
```

Don't forget to make your CSS selector more specific than those of Dojo, if you remove `.claro` from the CSS code above, then it will not work.

An example can be found on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n4ydv/

Comment: You miss understood actually. I need all dates selectable along with Today's date selected all the time. If today's date is 19/05/14 and it will be selected at any point of time and if user selects any other date lets assume that user selects 25/05/14. Now we should able to see both today's date and another selected date should be highlighted.

Comment: So what you actually want is the ability to select multiple dates?

Comment: Kind of but not actually multiselect. You can have a example of your windows desktop calender, where you can see the user can select only one date and if he select other than today's date then the today's date will be indicated in a black box border.